# for文で動的に作成したボタンのテキスト取得方法

Tags: android, android-studio

for文で作成されたボタンのテキストを取得する処理を実装したいです。
ボタン選択時にクリックしたボタンの識別をidを使わないで行いたいと考えているのですが、方法はありますでしょうか？
また、回答者様のお勧めの方法などがあれば、教えていただきたいです。
コードについては、不十分な部分があるかもしれませんが、その際はご指摘ください。

```
private Button button[] =new Button[20];

for(int i=0,j=0; i< button.length ;i++,j++) {

    button[i] =new Button(this);
    // Tag を設定する
    button[i].setText(data2[1][i]);//すでに存在する文字列をセット
    button[i].setId(i);
    button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick (View view) {

              //ここに処理を書きたいです

         }
    });
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                buttonWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(margins, margins, margins, margins);

        button[i].setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
        layout.addView(button[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

この場合すでにViewが取得できている状態なのでgetText()をコールするだけです。

```
     public void onClick (View view) {
          Log.d("test","text is " + ((Button)view).getText());
     }
```